# Newbie : Model testing difficult with build or save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a `Ownership` model with a `start_date` and a `end_date`. I defined a method in the **app/models/ownership.rb**, like this :

```rb
def current?
  self.start_date.present? && self.end_date.nil?
end
```

And I test this method in the **spec/models/ownership_spec.rb**

```rb
describe Ownership do

  let(:product) { FactoryGirl.create(:product) }
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

  before { @ownership = user.ownerships.build(product: product) }

    subject { @ownership }

    describe "when owning and giving date are nil" do
      before do
        @ownership.save
        @ownership.update_attributes(start_date: nil, end_date: nil, agreed: true)
      end
      it { should be_valid }
      @ownership.current?.should be_false

      describe "then product is owned" do
        before { @ownership.update_attributes(start_date: 1.day.ago) }

        it { should be_valid }
        @ownership.current?.should be_true
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But rspec doesn't like it and returns :

```rb
undefined method `current?' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Do you know why my `@ownership` seems to be nil to rspec ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put all assertions/checks to `it` blocks. Don't place naked checks like this.

```
it { should be_valid }
@ownership.current?.should be_false # incorrect scope here
```

Do this instead:

```
it { should be_valid }
it { subject.current?.should be_false }
```

Or better do this:

```
it { should be_valid }
its(:current?) { should be_false }
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick and efficient answer !